# How can I sum the elements of an array in a for loop and place these sums in an array for different values of n?- Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have list of numbers in a text document that I'm importing into python. The important part is in the code below. I am sending the F[i]'s into an array and would like to sum this array for fixed w[j] and changing i. I want to make the sum the first element of a new array and repeat this process for j=0,1,2,3.... n (n was defined earlier in the program). To explicitly write out what I'm trying to do-

```
NewArray[1]= sum((1.0/9000.0)*P[i]*np.cos(w[1]*t[i]))    

NewArray[2]= sum(((1.0/9000.0)*P[i]*np.cos(w[2]*t[i]))  
...  
...  
...  
NewArray[n]= sum ((1.0/9000.0)*P[i]*np.cos(w[n]*t[i]))
```

At this point, I have no idea how to keep w[j] constant while changing i without doing it manually. Unfortunately, this isn't an option because n=18000. Running the for loop with j as a seperate index changes j and i at the same time. Sorry, if the question is confusing. I wasn't entirely sure how to word it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
for line in f:
    line=line.strip()
    columns=line.split()
    t[i]=float (columns[0])
    P[i]=float (columns[3])
    Q[i]=float (columns[4])

    w[j]=2*np.pi*j/T

    F[i]=(1.0/9000.0)*P[i]*np.cos(w[j]*t[i])



    i=i+1
```

Comment: Have you tried `for x in range(1, n+1): NewArray[x] = sum((1.0/9000.0)*P[i]*np.cos(w[x]*t[i]))`?

Comment: I have but every time I try put the sum() function in a for loop with the indices, I get "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable"